# Handeling document upload and processing in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am going to make a service that lets the user upload a MS Excel file and process it with nodeJs, i tried this before and it was a very long process that takes a lot of resources.

So in a production enviroment where the server will have to deal with many instances of this service ( many uploads at the same time ) how can i deal with the workload ? 
any frameworks i can use or maybe a strategy ?

Answer (score 1):

There is plugin called `multer` in nodejs, you can combine this with `Amazon s3` through `multer-s3` to store the uploaded files. For Processing/Reading and manipulation excel file, there exists an npm package called `xlsx` that is good enough.

I believe when it comes to scaling or being able to process multiple requests, that will depend on the server size and other code factors that can be optimized from time to time.